# getting a calculated result from mixing records in the same table

Tags: filemaker

I am a particular situation on my hands that I do not what to call it, so I am just going to explain it! I am working on File-maker pro database for a university that keeps track of students that are majoring in education one of the tables keeps track of all of the standardized test taken by students that range from the following; **ACT, SAT, ETS, and Papa**. before when I made this table, all test stood alone or in other words you couldn't combine scores to make a passing grade. That has now changed with two test, PAPA and ETS. In order words, you can combine scores from each test to make one grade to pass.

Here is an example

lets just say for simplicity sake that you need a grand total of 10 for the PAPA and ETS test in order to pass those individual test

```
Test Name | Reading | Writing | Math | Total | pass/fail
--------------------------------------------------------
PAPA      |       2 |       2 |    2 |     6 |    FAILED
ets       |       1 |       2 |    6 |     9 |    FAILED
```

So A couple weeks ago.. this individual would not pass there standard test, but now this indivdual would hve passed because he/she has gotten a a 6 in the ETS Math and two 2's in Reading and writing in the PAPAS.

Here's what my current calculation looks like:

```
If (
  ReadingScore ≥ BasicTest::PassReading
    and MathScore ≥ BasicTest::PassMath
    and WritingScore ≥ BasicTest::PassWriting ;
  "PASSED" ;

  If ( Score >= BasicTest::QMScore ;
    If ( ReadingScore >= BasicTest::QMReading ;
      If ( MathScore >= BasicTest::QMMATH ;
        If ( WritingScore >= BasicTest::QMWriting ;
          "PASSED" ;
          "DOES NOT MEET WRITING REQUIREMENTS"
        ) ;
        "DOES NOT MEET MATH REQUIREMENTS"
      ) ;
      "DOES NOT MEET READING REQUIREMENTS"
    ) ;
    "FAILED"
  )
)
```

So my question here today is how should I approach this with the Filemaker pro application? Should I make this a report or should a just rebuild the table completely?!?!?!?

Comment: It depends on what your calculation currently looks like to determine whether the student has passed or not. In all likelihood, you'll only need to change that calculation to account for the new requirement. It may be an ugly calc, but that can be helped by using `Let` variables. Can you share what the current calc looks like?

Comment: This is the code now
If ( ReadingScore  ≥  BasicTest::PassReading and MathScore  ≥  BasicTest::PassMath  and WritingScore  ≥ BasicTest::PassWriting;"PASSED";
If(Score >= BasicTest::QMScore;
If(ReadingScore>= BasicTest::QMReading;
If(MathScore>=BasicTest::QMMATH;
If(WritingScore >= BasicTest::QMWriting;
"PASSED";
"DOES NOT MEET WRITING REQUIREMENTS");
"DOES NOT MEET MATH REQUIREMENTS");
"DOES NOT MEET READING REQUIREMENTS");
"FAILED")
)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure exactly how your calc matches up with your question (I *think* `Score` in your calc is the total of the other scores?), I think I can offer some pointers.

Given what you say and what the calc shows, I think the following are true:

- Given multiple tests, you're interested in the maximum score for each category.
- Each maximum score needs to be greater than the minimum score from either `BasicTest::Pass*` or `BasicTest::QM*`.
- The test taker passes if all their max scores are greater than all the test minimum scores **or** the total max scores is greater than the `BasicTest::QMScore`.

Given the above, I came up with the following calc:

```
Let (
  [
    _reading_score = Max ( papa_reading_score ; ets_reading_score ) ;
    _math_score    = Max ( papa_math_score    ; ets_math_score    ) ;
    _writing_score = Max ( papa_writing_score ; ets_writing_score ) ;
    _total_score   = _reading_score + _math_score + _writing_score ;

    _target_reading = Min ( BasicTest::PassReading ; BasicTest::QMReading ) ;
    _target_math    = Min ( BasicTest::PassMath    ; BasicTest::QMMath ) ;
    _target_writing = Min ( BasicTest::PassWriting ; BasicTest::QMWriting ) ;

    _pass_reading = ( _reading_score ≥ _target_reading ) ;
    _pass_math    = ( _math_score    ≥ _target_math    ) ;
    _pass_writing = ( _writing_score ≥ _target_writing ) ;

    _passed = ( _pass_reading and _pass_math and _pass_writing )
      or ( _total_score ≥ BasicTest::QMScore );

    _result = Case (
      _passed           ; "PASSED"                             ;
      not _pass_reading ; "DOES NOT MEET READING REQUIREMENTS" ;
      not _pass_math    ; "DOES NOT MEET MATH REQUIREMENTS"    ;
      not _pass_writing ; "DOES NOT MEET WRITING REQUIREMENTS" ;
                          "FAILED"
    )
  ] ;

  _result
)
```

Even if the above isn't exactly what you need, I hope it'll provide some direction. With a complicated calc like this, break it up into pieces with each piece (in this case, each variable assignment) being easy to understand.

Note that `Max` and `Min` can take many arguments and can also take fields that have multiple values (related fields in a one-to-many relationship or repeating fields), so if you have more than two scores or two tests to check for maximum and minimum values, just add them as more parameters.